# Strange SQL behavior: Variable not setting properly with unrelated computed column

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm running two different SQL queries and getting vastly different results:

### The Tables:

*mips*: This table is indexed on `time` and contains a `*_good` and `*_bad` field for each "metric" that I measure (round-trip time, re-transmitted bytes, etc). The fields are: `time`, `rtt_good`, `rtt_bad`, `rexb_good`, `rexb_bad`, `nae_good`, `nae_bad`, etc.

*metrics*: This table is indexed on `time`, `asn` (the network to which we delivered traffic), `cty` (the country in which we delivered that traffic), and `source` (the data center from which we delivered that traffic). So for a single "time" we have hundreds of thousands of rows. Each row tells us the total number of requests served (`reqs`), and various measured metrics about the traffic delivery (`rtt`, `rexb`, `nae`, etc)

The two tables are joined on the `time` column, which contains a UNIX timestamp. All other values are floats.

### Goal

Given the `rtt_good` (a value for round-trip time which we deem is "good", like 10ms), the `rtt_bad` (a value for round-trip time which we deem is "bad", like 5 seconds), and the `rtt` we can perform linear interpolation to provide a measure of "how good" or "how bad" the RTT is:

```
rtt_mips = (rtt - rtt_good) / (rtt_bad - rtt_good)
```

Since we have data for every possible `asn`, `cty`, and `source` - we often need to aggregate this data to answer more generic questions like "How does our RTT look in Mexico?". When aggregating, we perform a weighted average of the metric - weighted by the number of requests we serviced. For instance, the average RTT in Mexico would be:

```
select sum(rtt * reqs) / sum(reqs) as avg_rtt from metrics where cty = "mx"
```

Now **the issue** is that we don't always service every ASN in every country from every data source at every 5 minute interval. We may have a span of time where our Japan data center isn't serving **any** data to Mexico. This means that when we group these metrics by time, we have a lot of `NULL` rows:

```
+------+---------+
| time | avg_rtt |
+------+---------+
|  1   |   300   |
|  2   |  NULL   |
|  3   |   400   |
|  ... |   ...   |
```

To fix this, I wish to take the "last known" RTT and copy it down to the next row before computing the "relative good-ness" of the RTT:

```
+------+---------+------------+----------+---------+----------+
| time | avg_rtt | last_known | rtt_good | rtt_bad | rtt_mips |
+------+---------+------------+----------+---------+----------+
|  1   |   300   |    300     |   10     |  5000   |   math   |
|  2   |  NULL   |    300     |   10     |  5000   |   math   |
|  3   |   400   |    400     |   10     |  5000   |   math   |
|  ... |   ...   |    ...     |   ...    |   ...   |    ...   |
```

This can be accomplished with a combination of MySQL variables and `COALESCE` like so:

```
select @rtt := coalesce(rtt, @rtt) from metrics
```

If `rtt` is not `NULL`, we use `rtt`. If `rtt` **is** `NULL`, we use the `@rtt` variable which came from the previous row

Put all of that together, and you get **query 1**, below.

However I intend to use the output of this to draw graphs in JavaScript, so I wanted to multiply the `time` column by `1000` (to convert seconds to milliseconds). This results in **query 2**, which had different (and unexpected) behavior.

### Query 1:

```
select
    mips.time,
    @rtt := coalesce(sum(rtt*reqs)/sum(reqs), @rtt) as rtt,
    (coalesce(sum(rtt*reqs)/sum(reqs), @rtt) - rtt_good) / (rtt_bad - rtt_good) as rtt_mips
from
    mips
left join
    (
        select * from metrics where asn = '33095' and cty = 'us'
    ) t1 on mips.time = t1.time
group by time
order by time asc;
```

Result:

```
+------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| time       | rtt             | rtt_mips             |
+------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| 1521731100 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521731400 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521731700 | 12593           |  0.04197666666666667 |
| 1521732000 | 12593           |  0.04197666666666667 |
| 1521732300 | 12593           |  0.04197666666666667 |
| 1521732600 | 12593           |  0.04197666666666667 |
| 1521732900 | 41266.90234375  |  0.13755633333333334 |
| 1521733200 | 41266.90234375  |  0.13755634114583334 |
| 1521733500 | 41266.90234375  |  0.13755634114583334 |
| 1521733800 | 41266.90234375  |  0.13755634114583334 |
| 1521734100 | 41266.90234375  |  0.13755634114583334 |
| 1521734400 | 41266.90234375  |  0.13755634114583334 |
| 1521734700 | 41266.90234375  |  0.13755634114583334 |
| 1521735000 | 14979.439453125 | 0.049931333333333335 |
| 1521735300 | 11812.119140625 |  0.03937366666666667 |
| 1521735600 | 11812.119140625 |     0.03937373046875 |
| 1521735900 | 8738.2314453125 |  0.02912743333333333 |
| 1521736200 | 8738.2314453125 | 0.029127438151041667 |
| 1521736500 | 8738.2314453125 | 0.029127438151041667 |
| 1521736800 | 8738.2314453125 | 0.029127438151041667 |
+------------+-----------------+----------------------+
20 rows in set (0.22 sec)
```

### Query 2:

```
select
    mips.time * 1000 as time, -- The only line that changed
    @rtt := coalesce(sum(rtt*reqs)/sum(reqs), @rtt) as rtt,
    (coalesce(sum(rtt*reqs)/sum(reqs), @rtt) - rtt_good) / (rtt_bad - rtt_good) as rtt_mips
from
    mips
left join
    (
        select * from metrics where asn = '33095' and cty = 'us'
    ) t1 on mips.time = t1.time
group by time
order by time asc;
```

Result:

```
+---------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| time          | rtt             | rtt_mips             |
+---------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| 1521731100000 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521731400000 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521731700000 | 12593           |  0.04197666666666667 |
| 1521732000000 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521732300000 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521732600000 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521732900000 | 41266.90234375  |  0.13755633333333334 |
| 1521733200000 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521733500000 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521733800000 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521734100000 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521734400000 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521734700000 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521735000000 | 14979.439453125 | 0.049931333333333335 |
| 1521735300000 | 11812.119140625 |  0.03937366666666667 |
| 1521735600000 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521735900000 | 8738.2314453125 |  0.02912743333333333 |
| 1521736200000 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521736500000 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521736800000 | NULL            |                 NULL |
+---------------+-----------------+----------------------+
20 rows in set (0.41 sec)
```

### Question:

Why is it that when I change the `time` column to be `time * 1000` my variable stops getting set properly and my query starts returning `NULL`s?

### Version info:

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------------+
| version()       |
+-----------------+
| 10.1.26-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.10 sec)
```

### Response to @whoami

First, the results of the following query:

```
mysql> select * from mips where time = 1521731700000;
Empty set (0.15 sec)
```

And a similar query:

```
mysql> select * from mips where time = 1521731700;
+------------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+---------+--------+
| time       | rtt_good | rtt_bad | rexb_good | rexb_bad | nae_good | nae_bad | util_good | util_bad | fb_good | fb_bad | or_good | or_bad |
+------------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+---------+--------+
| 1521731700 |        0 |  300000 |         0 |       40 |       25 |     100 |         0 |       80 |       0 |    100 |       0 |    100 |
+------------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+---------+--------+
1 row in set (0.10 sec)
```

Then I tried grouping by `rtt_good` and `rtt_bad`, as well as multiplying the `time` column for `metrics` by 1000

Query:

```
select
    mips.time * 1000 as time,
    @rtt := coalesce(sum(rtt*reqs)/sum(reqs), @rtt) as rtt,
    (coalesce(sum(rtt*reqs)/sum(reqs), @rtt) - rtt_good) / (rtt_bad - rtt_good) as rtt_mips
from
    mips
left join
    (
        select time * 1000 as time, rtt, reqs from metrics where asn = '33095' and cty = 'us'
    ) t1 on mips.time = t1.time
group by time, rtt_good, rtt_bad
order by time asc;
```

Result:

```
+---------------+------+----------+
| time          | rtt  | rtt_mips |
+---------------+------+----------+
| 1521731100000 | NULL |     NULL |
| 1521731400000 | NULL |     NULL |
| 1521731700000 | NULL |     NULL |
| 1521732000000 | NULL |     NULL |
| 1521732300000 | NULL |     NULL |
| 1521732600000 | NULL |     NULL |
| 1521732900000 | NULL |     NULL |
| 1521733200000 | NULL |     NULL |
| 1521733500000 | NULL |     NULL |
| 1521733800000 | NULL |     NULL |
| 1521734100000 | NULL |     NULL |
| 1521734400000 | NULL |     NULL |
| 1521734700000 | NULL |     NULL |
| 1521735000000 | NULL |     NULL |
| 1521735300000 | NULL |     NULL |
| 1521735600000 | NULL |     NULL |
| 1521735900000 | NULL |     NULL |
| 1521736200000 | NULL |     NULL |
| 1521736500000 | NULL |     NULL |
| 1521736800000 | NULL |     NULL |
+---------------+------+----------+
20 rows in set (0.17 sec)
```

Because the time `1521736800000` does not exist in the `mips` table, it failed to properly join.

### Interesting Discovery

Even if I don't multiply the `time` column by `1000`, if I add the additional `group by` columns then the query still fails to operate how I expect:

```
select
    mips.time,
    @rtt := coalesce(sum(rtt*reqs)/sum(reqs), @rtt) as rtt,
    (coalesce(sum(rtt*reqs)/sum(reqs), @rtt) - rtt_good) / (rtt_bad - rtt_good) as rtt_mips
from
    mips
left join
    (
        select time, rtt, reqs from metrics where asn = '33095' and cty = 'us'
    ) t1 on mips.time = t1.time
group by time, rtt_good, rtt_bad
order by time asc;
```

Result:

```
+------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| time       | rtt             | rtt_mips             |
+------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| 1521731100 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521731400 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521731700 | 12593           |  0.04197666666666667 |
| 1521732000 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521732300 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521732600 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521732900 | 41266.90234375  |  0.13755633333333334 |
| 1521733200 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521733500 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521733800 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521734100 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521734400 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521734700 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521735000 | 14979.439453125 | 0.049931333333333335 |
| 1521735300 | 11812.119140625 |  0.03937366666666667 |
| 1521735600 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521735900 | 8738.2314453125 |  0.02912743333333333 |
| 1521736200 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521736500 | NULL            |                 NULL |
| 1521736800 | NULL            |                 NULL |
+------------+-----------------+----------------------+
20 rows in set (0.12 sec)
```

I feel like I've run into a strange edge case with how the storage engine is optimizing these queries.

Comment: may i know the reason for multiplying the time column

Comment: Your queries a bit ill-defined; since your `rtt_mips` are neither aggregated nor grouped by, the value chosen for them will be semi-random from among the possible values accompanying the grouped field(s) value(s); using an @variable complicates things even more; since the most apparent choice for non-aggregated, non-grouped expressions tends to be the first, anything that could affect the order rows are evaluated in can change the outcome.

Comment: try this and say me the output  `select * from mips where time=1521731700000;`

Comment: Also, are you initializing your session(@) variable before calling the queries? Such variables last for the lifetime of the connection.

Comment: then multiply the time column in metrics table also and check once

Comment: What about `rtt`? Which table is that coming from? (If you're expecting the expression for `rtt_mips` to be using the value from the `COALESCE(SUM())` expression, that is not what is happening; you cannot reference a select expression's alias in the select clause in which it is aliased).

Comment: What is it with sql programmers that they don't think they have to initialise varaibles?

Comment: If @rtt is initialized to null, then `coalesce(rtt, @rtt)` makes no sense, as where it is used is calculated before @rtt ever gets assigned; and `@rtt:=COALESCE(...,@rtt)` also becomes questionable because it will end up using the result of the last previously calculated as non-null result row at best.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest tweaking your question to have all fields qualified with their table name so we are not left somewhat guessing which ones come from which.

Comment: Regarding aliasing, just saying the `rtt` used in `rtt_mips` will be from the `metrics` table, not the field calculated before it. `@rtt` will never  have a value when `rtt_mips` is calculated, as `rtt_mips` is almost certainly calculated before the grouping that assigns a value to `@rtt` occurs.

Comment: It is possible that MySQL is calculating the SUM and assigning the @rtt for one time value before evaluating the rtt_mips for another time value; but I think this is more a peek at the underlying engine because of an ambiguity in the undefined evaluation order. The fact that the grouping and ordering change in the second query from an actual field value to a calculated one most likely affects this order. In any case, the expression for the `rtt_mips` column seems to make little sense in the context of the query as a whole, because it raises the question: `rtt_mips` for for which metric row?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167361/discussion-between-stevendesu-and-uueerdo).

Comment: I've amended my question with a more detailed explanation of the tables and the reasoning and expected result for the query. To prevent these comments from getting overly cluttered, I'm going to start deleting my own comments. Too many comments just makes it hard to follow a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work a bit more predictably:

```
SELECT mips.time * 1000 AS mips_time,
    @prev_rtt := coalesce(m_sum.weighted_rtt, @prev_rtt) as rtt,
    (coalesce(m_sum.weighted_rtt, @prev_rtt) - rtt_good) / (rtt_bad - rtt_good) as rtt_mips
FROM
    mips
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT m.time, sum(m.rtt*m.reqs)/sum(m.reqs) AS weighted_rtt
        FROM metrics AS m
        WHERE m.asn = '33095' and m.cty = 'us'
        GROUP BY m.time
    ) AS m_sum ON mips.time = m_sum.time
ORDER BY mips.time asc;
```

In my experience, `(@prev_rtt - rtt_good) / (rtt_bad - rtt_good) as rtt_mips` should work as well in this query, as the previous expression for `as rtt` should have assigned `@prev_rtt`; but that is venturing into "behaves this way, but not actually guaranteed by MySQL" territory as MySQL does not guarantee order of evaluation of select expressions.

Comment: Doing the aggregation in the subquery prior to joining with the `mips` table fixed my consistent issue and I was able to multiply `mips.time` by `1000` while still retaining the desired behavior :) Although to make the answer more clear, could you include the `SELECT mips.time * 1000 as time` bit?

Comment: Made the change, does that reflect your final query? I left the ordering by the field value, rather than select expression, as they should end up with the same ordering and guarantees the field value is used for ordering. (Also, aliased the result of the *1000 as mips_time for clarity.)

Comment: Looks great and runs perfectly :) Thank you for all of the help

Answer (score 0):

change query to this. You must initialize the var before you can calculate with it else it is NULL

```
select
    mips.time,
    @rtt := coalesce(sum(rtt*reqs)/sum(reqs), @rtt) as rtt,
    (coalesce(rtt, @rtt) - rtt_good) / (rtt_bad - rtt_good) as rtt_mips
from
    mips
left join
    (
        select * from metrics where asn = '33095' and cty = 'us'
    ) t1 on mips.time = t1.time
cross join ( select @rtt := 0 ) as init

group by time
order by time asc;
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem. This only replaces the `NULL` rows with `0` rows. The purpose of the variable is to retain the previous row's value if there is no data for a given `time`. Look at the difference in outputs -- particularly the behavior of row 4. Row 3 had data, so row 4 should copy that data. In the first query it did, in the second query it did not.